# virtual hosts on local machine ignored by Safari 7

Tags: apache, safari

I set up Apache on my OS X 10.9 machine and created a local virtual host `www.example.dev`

When I enter `www.example.dev`...

in **Firefox 26**, everything is fine and I get to see the local site

**Safari 7**, instead performs a Google search on `www.example.dev`

**How can I get Safari 7 behave like Firefox?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, Safari looks at the url to see if it's something that looks like a valid host.  Does it work if you explicitely prepend `http://`?

Try http://www.example.dev/ and see if that works.  Google Chrome has similar behavior, and prepending http:// fixes that.

Comment: This works! I didn't accept it yet because I still hope for a way to make it work without the http://

Comment: I don't have Safari here, but in Chrome, another way to bypass the search is to add a `/` at the end.  Does that work for you?

Comment: You are my hero! Thanks!